# Audio is unable to play via javascript on some mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I'm trying to do a simple thing. I want some audio to play exactly after 10 seconds when the user enters the webpage. I used the following code

```
var aud=new Audio("someAudio.mp3");
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function(){aud.play()}, 10000);
});
```

It is working perfectly fine on desktop browsers. However, the audio is not playing in **some** mobile browsers like Google Chrome though it is working in Firefox. What may be the possible reason for this and how to fix it? I saw some similar questions but didn't find a suitable answer.
Thanks in advance

Comment: it's a new-ish security policy: touch to play. if the feature works like it's supposed to, you can't bypass it...

Comment: But Dandavis, it is working in mobile Firefox and all desktop browsers

Comment: It doesn't look like mobile Chrome supports `Audio` yet. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement

Comment: Pmahomme, can you suggest a possible alternative?

Comment: Yes i know, and it used to work in chrome mobile before they changed it a few weeks ago...

Comment: Dandavis, it will be very kind of you if you let me know the trick

Comment: what part of `no` did i leave unclear? it CANNOT be done. give up now.

Comment: @dandavis have a look again. This time click the Mobile tab, Chrome isn't even listed.

Comment: Can I use flash for this?

Comment: no, there is no flash on chrome mobile. :(  i don't like the rule, but it must be followed..

Comment: @pmahomme: fair enough, the page needs updating. regardless, i assure you it's supported. ;)

Comment: But I visited many sites on my android chrome where I was able to hear some audios like http://www.playtictactoe.org

Comment: @VibhavAggarwal: i don't hear anything on that link without touching the screen. if you touch/click, then you can use the touch event to call the audio.play() command (or something that does something that then calls the play() command, it just has to be rooted in a user interaction event)

Comment: one sneaky way around the rule is to mute the audio, show a screen-blocking div as a "splash screen", and when they click() that splash screen to enter the page, play() the muted audio. You can then un-mute the audio and play() it again in the future from JS w/o further user interaction.

Comment: Actually the game in the link I provided is a flash game. So, the point is flash IS supported in android chrome. Also I made another program associated with touch event to play sound but facing the same problem- working on pc not working on android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to do a simple thing. I want some audio to play exactly after 10 seconds when the user enters the webpage.

You can't unless there has been user interaction.

Handle a `click` event for some element.  In that event handler, play some other audio.  (This audio can be silent!)  After 10 seconds have passed from load, if the user has touched/clicked something, and you've done this, you should be able to play your audio file.

Comment: I've been searching for this solution for weeks. Thank you very much!